# Excel 2010 locking cells based on the value in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel 2010 is it possible to lock or disable editing of one or more cells based on the value set in another cell.

My idea was to have a drop down list in Cell 1A with, for example, locked and unlocked.  Based on what was selected in the drop down list the remainder of row 1 is editable.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible if you use VBA.  The basic idea would be to write an event handler for when the worksheet in question is modified.

In this event handler, you first need to check if the modified cell is within the range you want to lock.  If it is, you should check the value of cell A1 to see if it's in a "locked state".  If it is, you can then simply ignore the event.

See [this reference](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm) site for some examples.  You can also see [this site](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Workbook_events_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/441.html) for a list of events you may want to use.